# Spring Boot 2.0 pagination with oracle is not working

Tags: java, oracle, rest, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I currently migrate from Spring Boot 1.4 -> 2.0, then I have a problem:

```
@GetMapping("/sample")
public Page<SampleDTO> doSomethings(@RequestParam("name") String name, Pageable pageable)
```

My Repository:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Sample> {
        Page<Sample> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

So, when I call an API:

```
http://localhost:8088/api/v1/sample?name=abc&page=0&size=10&sort=name,asc
```

I noticed JPA has translated to this query:

**Spring Boot 1.5**

```
select * 
from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ 
from ( select ... from sample sample0_ where upper(sample0_.name) like upper(?) 
        order by sample0_.name asc ) 
row_ where rownum <= ?) where rownum_ > ?
```

**Spring Boot 2.0**

```
select ...
from sample sample0_ 
where upper(sample0_.name) like upper(?) 
order by sample0_.name asc fetch first ? rows only

-->>> 2018-08-14 14:45:04 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Which is not correct for Oracle query. Is it a bug ?

Comment: Can I see your query, and not the translated one

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I just call the methods "findByNameContainingIgnoreCase", JpaRepository will handle the rest. Thanks

Comment: Have you set any database dialect? And try setting spring.jpa.database=default

Comment: Hi Simon add spring.jpa.database=default did show the problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So in Spring Boot 1.5, using only without specify any dialect everything is working fine:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

But when I migrated to Spring Boot 2.0, dialect has to be defined with:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Otherwise you will see the message:

```
2018-08-14 17:11:02 WARN  c.z.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
```

Thanks to @Simon Martinelli's comment. It really help me to spot my mistake :)